# Can I use an edit path with conditional for ruby on rails link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to, restful-url

I wan to create a link_to tag with a conditional for example:

**The below code probably doesn't work... do not try**

```
link_to "Edit postal address", edit_postal_address_path( :condition => {:organization_id => @organization_id } )
```

I want to edit the postal address with the organization_id that I have in a variable. Is there a slick way of doing this or would I have to take the long way?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. Are you trying to edit the postal address record that has the `id` that is stored in that `@organization_id` variable?

Comment: i did not understand, do you need to use the organization_id in the edit postal address method?

Comment: My postal address model has a column called organization_id. I want to edit the postal address where organization_id = @organization_id.

Comment: I gotcha now. Take a look at D3mon's answer below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
link_to "Edit postal address", edit_postal_address_path( PostalAddress.where("organization_id = ?", @organization_id)
```

This relationship should be each Organization `has_one` PostalAddress

Comment: Just wanted to add that I had better luck with this method..  PostalAddress.find(:first, :conditions => {:organization_id => @organization_id})